# Ordering in subqueries

Tags: postgresql, order-by

This is my query:

```
select locid,tlid,locdescription from (

  select locid, tlid, locdescription
  from 
  trip_log left join trip_log_det on tlid=tldtripid 
  left join locations on tldlocation=locid
  where tlid=50 order by tldid 

) as foo group by locid,tlid,locdescription
```

The point of using a subquery is to get data back ordered as per the internal query, so sorted by `tldid`. I do not need `tldid` in the data as it is a serial column and it would nullify the `group by` statement.

Is there a way to tell the subquery to maintain the ordering of the internal query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a subquery at all. But you have to decide what ordering you want.

After the `group by` there is no `tldid` values any more. And every group will be made by collapsing many rows (with **different `tldid` values**) into one row. Which of them should be used for the ordering? Is it the maximum, the mimimum or some other?

You can write for example:

```
select locid, tlid, locdescription
from 
  trip_log left join trip_log_det on tlid = tldtripid 
  left join locations on tldlocation = locid
where tlid = 50 
group by locid, tlid, locdescription
order by min(tldid) ;
```

---

In Postgres, you could also use the non-standard `DISTINCT ON` syntax to achieve the same result. This is more flexible, as you can have the `tldid` and other (non-grouped) columns in the `select` list as well:

```
select distinct on (locid, tlid, locdescription)
    locid, tlid, locdescription
from 
  trip_log left join trip_log_det on tlid = tldtripid 
  left join locations on tldlocation = locid
where tlid = 50 
order by locid, tlid, locdescription,
         tldid asc ;
```